# Why is kubernetes' completion status not getting updated?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a job that has the default backoff limit set to 6. In the first 5 attempts it fails and in the last attempt it passes.

As per the logs, I see it passed but the completion status is still 0/1

Here is the snippet of code which is running inside the container.

```
for i in $entities_to_load; do
  IS_SUCCESS=$(load_config "$i") # returns 0 or 1 (failure)
  log_info "Exit status for load config [$i]: ${IS_SUCCESS}"
  if [[ ${IS_SUCCESS} -eq 1 ]]; then
    log_info "Failed to load $i entity"
    cat response.txt
    exit ${IS_SUCCESS}
  else
    log_info "Successfully loaded the ${i} entity"
exit 0
```

Here are the logs from the last attempt which passed

```
+ eric-bss-coba-cm-baseconfig-job-xd7bz › baseconfig-provisioner-job
eric-bss-coba-cm-baseconfig-job-xd7bz baseconfig-provisioner-job {"version":"0.3.0","timestamp":"2020-12-29T07:16:13.649+00:00","severity":"info","service_id":"eric-bss-coba-cm","message":"Successfully loaded the Currency entity"}
eric-bss-coba-cm-baseconfig-job-xd7bz baseconfig-provisioner-job {"version":"0.3.0","timestamp":"2020-12-29T07:16:14.545+00:00","severity":"info","service_id":"eric-bss-coba-cm","message":"Successfully loaded the Measure entity"}
eric-bss-coba-cm-baseconfig-job-xd7bz baseconfig-provisioner-job {"version":"0.3.0","timestamp":"2020-12-29T07:16:16.633+00:00","severity":"info","service_id":"eric-bss-coba-cm","message":"Successfully loaded the UnitOfMeasurement entity"}
eric-bss-coba-cm-baseconfig-job-xd7bz baseconfig-provisioner-job {"version":"0.3.0","timestamp":"2020-12-29T07:16:16.875+00:00","severity":"info","service_id":"eric-bss-coba-cm","message":"Successfully loaded the EventReportingInterval entity"}
eric-bss-coba-cm-baseconfig-job-xd7bz baseconfig-provisioner-job {"version":"0.3.0","timestamp":"2020-12-29T07:16:17.357+00:00","severity":"info","service_id":"eric-bss-coba-cm","message":"Successfully loaded the NumberingScheme entity"}
- eric-bss-coba-cm-baseconfig-job-xd7bz
```

Here is what the completions say

```
NAME                                       COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
eric-bss-bam-faultmap-mutator-1609226700   1/1           3s         3m44s
eric-bss-coba-cm-baseconfig-job            0/1           18m        18m
eric-bss-coba-integration-schema-job       1/1           18s        18m
```

Here are logs from the `kubectl describe jobs.batch/my-job`

```
Completions:    1
Start Time:     Tue, 29 Dec 2020 12:40:08 +0530
Pods Statuses:  0 Running / 0 Succeeded / 0 Failed
```

Here are the events from kubectl

```
Events:
  Type     Reason                Age                From            Message
  ----     ------                ----               ----            -------
  Normal   SuccessfulCreate      25m                job-controller  Created pod: eric-bss-coba-cm-baseconfig-job-xd7bz
  Normal   SuccessfulDelete      19m                job-controller  Deleted pod: eric-bss-coba-cm-baseconfig-job-xd7bz
  Warning  BackoffLimitExceeded  19m (x2 over 19m)  job-controller  Job has reached the specified backoff limit
```

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM <base-image>
WORKDIR /baseconfig
COPY . $WORKDIR
RUN chmod +x baseconfig.sh
CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

Here is my invocation of this script from the helm job spec

```
command: [ "sh" ]
args: [ "-c", "/baseconfig/baseconfig.sh SERVICE_NAME {{.Values.service.port}}"]
```

As you can see that the logs printed fine and it should have exited with 0 status, the job should have marked it as completed and the same should have been visible in the completions but it didn't. It instead, said, "BackoffLimitExceeded" and failed the deployment.

I am unable to identify the problem here.

Comment: can u please add output of kubectl describe jobs/<job name>

Comment: @AbhijitGaikwad sure, I missed that.

Comment: @AbhijitGaikwad added them

Comment: i dont understand why "Pods Statuses" is showing all 0, i was hoping it would say 7 Failed

Comment: Yes, probably because of my restartPolicy: OnFailure

Comment: can you try k get  jobs/<job name> -o yaml

Comment: I started a new run now and didn't take it. Are you interested in the seeing the spec for the job ? I can paste my helm template in that case.

Comment: did you figure out the issue?

Comment: Nope not yet. I have added it on k8s github too